# I want to turn an equality statement into a function

Tags: expression-manipulation

I've got a statement (condition?) that I want to integrate.

```
r'[t] == (2*(c + A*t)*(1 + z))/(2 + z)
```

What's the best way to integrate just the RHS of this equality?  Ideally, I'd just like to turn this into a function such that:

```
r'[t] -> (2*(c + A*t)*(1 + z))/(2 + z)
```

And then integrate r'[t] like so:

```
Integrate[r'[t],{t,t1,t0}]
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: It looks as if OP does not want to invest any efforts in learning the basics of MMA, but wants us to solve all his problems. Further, this question had recently received an answer. I personally twice answered the OP's questions on this (or a close) subject. I vote to close this or comparable questions of OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is called an equation. We may store it in a variable `eq`:

eq = r'[t] == (2*(c + A*t)*(1 + z))/(2 + z);

Now to define `r'`  we only use the right hand side:

```
Clear[r]
r'[t_] = eq[[2]]
```

This we can integrate:

```
Integrate[r'[t], {t, t1, t2}]
```

giving:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is also a place where ApplySides might be useful. In this case, to apply the Integrate to both sides of the equation:

```
eq = ApplySides[Integrate[#, {t, t1, t2}] &, r'[t] == (2*(c + A*t)*(1 + z))/(2 + z)]
```

[image]

To get just the left hand side take the first part

```
eq[[1]]
```

To get just the right hand side, take the second part

```
eq[[2]]
```

Comment: This is actually quite clever, but it still doesn't answer the question.  The LHS represents the function I would like to use, but it's unusable in this state.  That is, I can't actually calculate the derivative from this.

Comment: @Quarkly -- see update. It's usually pretty easy to extract pieces of expressions using Part, i..e, [[ ]].